# Can webpack change the source of assets?

Tags: javascript, webpack, phaser-framework

Below is my webpack.config.js. I'm working on a phaser game with a restAPI. My assets are in a folder off  the root. My problem is I compiled with webpack and it changed the code in the boot scene of phaser to look for my assets in 'build/assets'. There is no such folder, so in the browser it's giving me the 404 not found errors. Is there a way to prevent this in the webpack.config? Or should I just copy the assets folder inside the build folder?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: 'project.bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        use: { loader: 'babel-loader' },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: [/\.vert$/, /\.frag$/],
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'CANVAS_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
      'WEBGL_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: yep, just copy (e.g. using CopyWebpackPlugin). You should not mix source and build files anyway.

Comment: okay that worked on adding the CopyWebpackPlugin with the appropriate additions to the webpack.config.js. But does webpack change the code? Apart from "minimizing"? In my source code I don't have it looking in the build folder for the assets and when I run it in the browser the console gives me the 404 error.